# A web application as a logging frontend for Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, logging

I was looking for a web application that hopefully catches log messages sent from Ruby programs and display them , much like the [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) program (in integration with log4r). I tried to Google anything related but with no success so far. Does anybody have a suggestion ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of web viewers for log4j logs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j). Some of them are web-based.